# Delphi - TObjectDictionary giving Invalid Pointer on Free

Tags: delphi

Delphi XE6 - I am using TObjectDictionary, with a custom class.  I create, add, and later Free.  It I do JUST that, everything is fine.  If I do a "TryGetValue", I get an "Invalid Pointer Operation" on my free.  The TryGetValue works fine, gives the proper result, but causes an issue later...

Here is my code.

```
 type
  TWordRec = class
  public
    RemoveAlways: Boolean; // Is this CORP LLC, etc?
    RemoveRestricted: Boolean;
    Replace: Boolean;
    ReplaceWith: string;
    Constructor Create(B1, B2, B3: Boolean; S1: String); overload;
  end;
...
constructor TWordRec.Create(B1, B2, B3: Boolean; S1: String);
begin
  self.RemoveAlways := B1; // Is this CORP LLC, etc?
  self.RemoveRestricted := B2;
  self.Replace := B3;
  self.ReplaceWith := S1;
end;
```

I add my test code on a button...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
CurrentDictEntry : TWordRec;
FoundIt : Boolean;

begin

ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

WordDict := TObjectDictionary<String, TWordRec>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
WordDict.Add('CO', TWordRec.Create(True, False, False, ''));
WordDict.Add('CORP', TWordRec.Create(True, False, False, ''));
WordDict.Add('CORPORATION', TWordRec.Create(True, False, False, ''));

CurrentDictEntry := TWordRec.Create(False, False, False, '');

// If I remove next two code lines, everything is fine
// With these 2 lines, I get error ON WordDict.Free;
FoundIt := WordDict.TryGetValue('CORP', CurrentDictEntry);
if FoundIt = True then ShowMessage('Found');

CurrentDictEntry.Free;
WordDict.Free;
end;
```

Why can't I free my WordDict?  If I just free WordDict (i.e. comment out CurrentDictEntry.free), the WordDict.Free works without an Invalid Pointer operation, but then I get a memory leak on exiting my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
CurrentDictEntry.Free;
```

At this point, `CurrentDictEntry` is a value that is contained in the container. And you cannot free the values in this container because the container owns them. If you try to free values, then the container will later try to free them again, the classic double free problem.

Once you've told the container to own the values, you must not free them.

The other problem is that you leak a `TWordRec`.

```
CurrentDictEntry := TWordRec.Create(False, False, False, '');
FoundIt := WordDict.TryGetValue('CORP', CurrentDictEntry);
```

The first line creates a new object and holds a reference to it in `CurrentDictEntry`. The second line then overwrites `CurrentDictEntry` and now you have no references at all to the object that you just created, and it is thus leaked.

Your code should look like this:

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;

WordDict := TObjectDictionary<String, TWordRec>.Create([doOwnsValues]);
try
  WordDict.Add('CO', TWordRec.Create(True, False, False, ''));
  WordDict.Add('CORP', TWordRec.Create(True, False, False, ''));
  WordDict.Add('CORPORATION', TWordRec.Create(True, False, False, ''));

  FoundIt := WordDict.TryGetValue('CORP', CurrentDictEntry);
  if FoundIt then 
    ShowMessage('Found');
finally
  WordDict.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think I am, but I am probably misunderstanding something....  I am ONLY freeing a NEW class Instance, which should NOT be owned by the container, and then freeing the container itself...

Comment: Negative. It's as I said. You get a reference to a value owned by the container and then free it. Then the container frees it again.

Comment: OK.  But if the ONLY Free that I do is WordDict.Free, (NO Invalid Pointer on close), I get an "Unexpected Memory Leak... 13-20 bytes: TWordRec x 1.  This is my CurrentDictEntry variable.  If the WordDict owns it, why isn't it cleaning it up?  How do I ensure that the memory is freed?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the instance you create at all. So when TryGetValue finds something your reference is lost and you get a memory leak.

Comment: @user1009073 Well, you created a new object when you did this: `CurrentDictEntry := TWordRec.Create(False, False, False, '');`. And then you leaked that object when you overwrote the value of `CurrentDictEntry`.

Comment: You are welcome. I had not spotted the leak to begin with an concentrated on the double free. Other "free" advice: don't test `bool=True` or `bool=False`, test `bool` or `not bool`; always use `try/finally` when your code is the lifetime owner.

Comment: I understand your comment on try/finally, but why bool/not bool?